# JS highlight overwriting text issue

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which highlights numbers, but it seems to overwrite other numbers. How can I fix this?

**JavaScript**

```
var numbers, spans;
numbers = $(".range").html().replace(/\s/g, '').split("");
spans = "<span>" + numbers.join("</span>\n<span>") + "</span>";
$(".range").html(spans);
```

**CSS**

```
p.range span:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+4) {
 color:red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p class="range">123345232</p>

<p class="range">34242425232</p>
```

When I run this, I am getting the following incorrect output:

```
1 2 3 3 4 5 2 3 2

1 2 3 3 4 5 2 3 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have your jQuery is that it is saving the first range and outputting it to the other p.range elements. In my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jawilliams346614/vyLkj8uv/) you can see how this can be accomplished using .each

Below is the updated jQuery. By wrapping in a .each and using $(this), it insures that we only change the range we are currently working on.

```
var numbers, spans;

$('.range').each(function() {
    numbers = $(this).html().replace(/\s/g, '').split("");
    spans = "<span>" + numbers.join("</span>\n<span>") + "</span>";
    $(this).html(spans);
});
```